# What's the difference between write() and push() for PassThrough streams?

Tags: node.js, testing, stream

Say I'm using node's [PassThrough stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) to test my stream utility and I want some data to come out of my stream.

```
var s = new require('stream').PassThrough();

s.push(x);  // <==== Are these identical?
s.write(x);
```

Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No**, they are not identical.

[**push**](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) is for implementing a readable stream. It pushes data into the read queue, which can then be read by calling read(). If it is called with null then it will signal the end of the data (EOF). See the Note given :

> **Note: This function should be called by Readable implementors, NOT by consumers of Readable streams.**

To implement a stream, certain methods must be written by the developer, given [here](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementors).

```
Use-case                                       Class       Method(s) to implement
Reading only                                   Readable    _read
Writing only                                   Writable    _write
Reading and writing                            Duplex      _read, _write
Operate on written data, then read the result  Transform   _transform, _flush
```

push must only be used for streams capable of read() i.e. **Readable**, **Duplex** and **Transform** streams. It must only be used inside these functions _read, _transform or _flush. PassThrough is an implementation of Transform.

---

[**write**](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) is supposed to be used by the user of a writable stream.

> This method writes some data to the underlying system, and calls the
>   supplied callback once the data has been fully handled.

If you intend to use a Writable stream (write into it) then use write. push is not an alternative for write. Use write for PassThrough.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I was confusing myself by reasoning that mocking stream behavior in a test is kinda like implementing a stream. Only calling `push` from `_read`, `_transform`, or `_flush` is pretty unambiguous.  Any insight into why `push` isn't `_push`?

Comment: push is used not just in stream, but for low level objects like arrays and queues (based on arrays). So maybe they are using the same or have modified it. It is dependent on the buffer they use internally.

Comment: Just for reference, the link to the node stream docs "API for stream implementers" has changed (implementor => implementer, AmEng vs. BrEng). Correct one is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementers)